# How to create a formula for a Period/Fourier Series from a set of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Please bear with me as I ask this question, I am sort of having to 'relearn' (or indeed just learn), way more about Math these days than I ever was taught in school, and so a lot of concepts and terminology can be alien to me (e.g. the difference between a series and sequence and the various types of series in existence).

I basically want to create two series of numbers, which will then be plotted on a graph like so: [How to derive a formula for plotting points on an xy grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296119/how-to-derive-a-formula-for-plotting-points-on-an-xy-grid) . After many conversations, head scratching and reading, I THINK I understand correctly that I need to create what is called a 'Periodic Series' in order to generate these sequences of numbers:

```
0,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-1,0
```

```
0,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,0,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,3,3
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is create a 'spiral', but in a sort of 'minecraft' (fixed chess/style grid), whereby a set of numbers (as above) will be created from an `index` ranging from 0 (or 1) to n. Any help on how to create a formula for deriving these series from an index, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There isn't going to be a nice formula, since this is really a piecemeal of different sequences. Why not just create a large array of these values in your program, and then access elements as you need? It's much easier to do this, since the pattern is clear (1 0, 2 1s, followed by dropping 1 to -1 by 1s, 3 -1s, followed by raising -1 to 2, 4 2s, etc)

Comment: I've been trying to do something like this (except 'flat' as opposed to a shell), and then somehow forcing it into a grid: https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/286tqb/3d_golden_spiral_equation/

Comment: That's just unnecessary and can lead to numerical precision issues. I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: You want [OEIS sequence A274923](https://oeis.org/A274923) and [OEIS sequence A174344](https://oeis.org/A174344).

Comment: ah yes that is it! thanks!! Now to figure out how to do it with code!